# Is there some algorithm to find the shortest path in the context of genetics and breeding?

Tags: shortest-path, genetics

In genetics and breeding, we typically have two parent genotype (may or may not be the same) which can produce a set of offspring with certain probability (assuming simple Mendelian inheritance).

I am looking for a way to determine given a set of parent, what is the shortest path to a particular offspring genotype (and yes, I am talking about breeding flowers in Animal Crossing!).

This seems to be very similar to the shortest path problem, but now the edges is given by two nodes interacting with each other. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Maybe try and ask your question here: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/ since it is more science related